# How to impose this exclusion constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exclusion-constraint

I have a key-value table.

```
CREATE TABLE keyvalues (
  key TEXT NOT NULL,
  value TEXT
)
```

I want to impose a constraint that if a key has an entry with NULL value, it cannot have any other entries.
How do I do that?

To clarify:
I want to allow ("key1", "value1"), ("key1", "value2"). But if I have ("key2", NULL), I want to not allow ("key2", "value3").

Comment: Huh? key is `NOT NULL` it can't have a `NULL` value. You are going to show some (pseudo)code explaining what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean an entry that looks like ("key", NULL).  That is, the value field is NULL.  I want to allow ("key1", "value1"), ("key1", "value2").  But if I have ("key2", NULL), I want to not allow ("key2", "value3").

Comment: Since PostgreSQL supports [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) you can explore `BEFORE INSERT`.

Comment: What if you have a value present for a key and try to insert a row with the same key and a NULL value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger, like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
 if exists (select 1 from keyvalues key = new.key and value is null) then 
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'Key-value not allowed';
  end if;
  RETURN new;
end;
$function$
;
```

Then you create the trigger on the table

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_table
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON keyvalues
    FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();
```

And test it:

```sql
insert INTO keyvalues 
SELECT 'a','a'
```

OK

```sql
insert INTO keyvalues 
SELECT 'a','b'
```

OK

```sql
insert INTO keyvalues 
SELECT 'b',null
```

OK

```sql
insert INTO keyvalues 
SELECT 'b','b'
```

`ERROR: Key-value not allowed`